# I am getting a name not defined error despite defining the variable

Tags: python, variables, discord.py, definition

I have defined a variable but I am getting a "name not defined" error regardless of where I place the code using the variable or where I place the variable definition code.

In this instance, the defining code is as follows:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

The line that is throwing an error is:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)
```

If I were to use the following code instead as an example:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
```

Then I have no errors, but that's not very dynamic and not what I'm looking for.

Regardless of where these blocks of code are placed, the same error is thrown and I don't understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback and add a fallback prefix if 'prefixes.json' does not have stored prefix for a guild. Use `return prefixes.get(str(message.guild.id), '!')` to use `!` as default prefix.

Comment: @nevus Sorry I'd missed your message. Just as of now I'd managed to solve the issue by running the line
`from cogs.Prefixes import get_prefix`
My apologies if I'd wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd managed to solve the issue by running
`from cogs.Prefixes import get_prefix` in my main file.